# Mod_rewrite will accept one string but not another

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

Can somebody please tell me what's going on...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^contacto/?$ index.php?seccion=contacto [L]
RewriteRule ^contactar/?$ index.php?seccion=contacto [L]
```

I want "contacto" to take me to "index.php?seccion=contacto", but it just takes me to "contacto.php" ignoring my rule completely. The funny thing is that if I change the string "contacto" to something else like in the second line, it works, taking me to "index.php?seccion=contacto"

There are no other .htaccess on the root or any subfolders. I have a fresh copy of Wamp (latest version) with Apache 2.4 and Php 7.2

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, a `RewriteBase` directive is required when you have rewrite rules in a .htaccess file. But that must not explain your issue.

Comment: @hakre no, it's not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the MultiViews option enabled on your Apache setup. Add `Options -MultiViews` at the top of your `.htaccess` file to disable it.

`MultiViews` doesn't play well with rewrite rules because it tries to translate URI like 'contact' into 'contact.en.php' or 'contact.fr.php' depending on the accept-language headers sent in the request.